# bitscan (bsf) on std::bitset ? Or similar

Tags: c++, bitset

I'm doing a project that involves solving some NP-hard graph problems. Specifically triangulation of Bayesian networks...

Anyway, I'm using std::bitset for creating an adjacency matrix and this is very nice... But I would like to scan the bitset using a bsf instruction. E.g. **not** using a while loop.

Anybody know if this is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the STL that comes with gcc 4.0.0, the bitset methods `_Find_first` and `_Find_next` already do what you want. Specifically, they use `__builtin_ctzl()` (described [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/gcc/Other-Builtins.html)), which should use the appropriate instruction. (I would guess that the same applies for older versions of gcc.)

And the nice thing is that bitset already does the right thing: single instruction if it's a bitset that fits within a single unsigned long; a loop over the longs if it uses several. In case of a loop, it's a loop whose length is known at compile time, with a handful of instructions, so it might be fully unrolled by the optimizer. I.e. it would probably be hard to beat bitset by rolling your own.

Comment: Okay, I suppose it would be best to make a struct that wraps std:bitset methods, so that missing functionality could be implemented for other compilers/systems using #ifdefs...
- Thanks...

Comment: hello, what does it mean to be a builtin function? Why isn't it officially documented and is publicly accessible?

Comment: Here it's referring to functions provided by the gcc compiler (rather than a library), see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html (and other articles around there).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::bitset::to_ulong`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/to_ulong/) and then BSF it(you'll need a custom contian for something bigger that 32bits though, or some way to get references to each 32/64 set of bits.

for BSF on MSVC you can use [`_BitScanForward`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfd9z0bb%28VS.80%29.aspx) else you can use something from [here](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/BitScan)

You might also want to look into using [BitMagic](http://bmagic.sourceforge.net/) instead

Comment: I've had a look at BitMagic, but it's dynamic sizes, and I can get more speed with static sizes...
And to_ulong() is defined to throw an exception if the bitset is larger than a unsigned long, so that won't do it...

Comment: Would a vector of 32-bit bitsets help?

Comment: Imo, the best option is to roll your own class, then you can integrate the bsf into the class. And std::bitset can be used as a base, seeing as its source is given in the header

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you might consider looking at [BITSCAN](https://www.biicode.com/pablodev/pablodev/bitscan/master) C++ library for bit array manipulation and [Ugraph](https://www.biicode.com/pablodev/pablodev/graph/master) for managing bit-encoded  undirected graphs. Since it is my code I will not add additional comments on this.

Hope it helps! (If it does I would be interested in any feedback).

Comment: Interesting, I finished this project years ago, but ended up with a fully header based implementation, see:
https://gist.github.com/jonasfj/4a6a9e58572f8e9e717f
(or the full source http://jonasfj.dk/blog/2010/12/triangulation-project/)